# Possible memory leak with malloc, struct, std::string, and free

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, memory-leaks

I've a situation like the following, and I'm not sure whether or not the std::string elements of the struct leak memory or if this is ok. Is the memory allocated by those two std::strings deleted when `free(v)` is called?

```
struct MyData
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
};

void* v = malloc(sizeof(MyData));
```

...

```
MyData* d = static_cast<MyData*>(v);
d->s1 = "asdf";
d->s2 = "1234";
```

...

```
free(v);
```

Leak or not?

I'm using the void-pointer because I have another superior struct, which consists of an enum and a void-pointer. Depending on the value of the enum-variable, the void* will point to different data-structs.

Example:

enum-field has EnumValue01 => void-pointer will point to a malloc'd MyData01 struct

enum-field has EnumValue02 => void-pointer will point to a malloc'd MyData02 struct

Suggestions for different approaches are very appreciated, of course.

Comment: It looks like you are somehow reinventing polymorphism. Are you aware of all the modern programming techniques available in C++ ? Your use of `malloc`/`free` suggests that you don't.

Comment: The different data-structs don't have anything in common. So I thought of using an enum and a void* Would it be better to create an empty pure virtual base class and let all the data-structs inherit that base class?

Comment: Can't really tell without knowing your specific situation, but if the structures are to be stored in the same super-structure, they **do** have something in common ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a leak indeed. free doesn't call MyData destructor (after all it's a C function which doesn't know anything about C++ stuff). Either you should use new/delete instead of malloc/free:

```
MyData* d = new MyData;
d->s1 = "asdf";
d->s2 = "1234";
delete d;
```

or call destructor by yourself:

```
void* v = malloc(sizeof(MyData));
MyData* d = new (v) MyData; // use placement new instead of static_cast
d->s1 = "asdf";
d->s2 = "1234";
...
d->~MyData();
free(v);
```

as sharptooth noted you can't directly use memory allocated by malloc as a MyData struct without initialization, so you have to do it by yourself as well. To initialize MyData using already allocated memory you need to use placement new (see in the code above).

Comment: You sould call the constructor, too: `::new (v) MyData;` with using `#include <new>`

Comment: But `MyData` is a struct, not a class, it doesn't have a destructor.

Comment: @Naszta: yes, thanks, already fixed this. copy/paste is error-prone indeed.

Comment: @wormsparty: `struct MyData {};` = `class MyData { public: };` Struct is a class, where the default inherit is public and not private.

Comment: @wormsparty: structs and classes are the same thing in C++ (except for default visibility which is not relevant here), so they do have constructors and destructors.

Comment: @wormsparty: Yes, it does. And `std::string` most certainly does.

Comment: @Naszta: To be picky, "struct is a class" is misleading. Speaking accurately, both `struct` and `class` as keywords are used in the definition of a User-Defined Type. Default member and inheritance visibility depend on which keyword you used, but otherwise the semantics are equivalent no matter what keyword you used to create your User-Defined Type.

Comment: That would mean that any C code compiled in C++ using `malloc` and `free` would be leaking memory, wouldn't it?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: to be picky there is "Classes" chapter (number 9) in C++ standard which specifies how classes are defined, and they are defined with 'class-key' which is one of 'class', 'struct' and 'union'. So "struct is a class" is quite close to what standard says.

Comment: @wormsparty: any C code would contain only what is called POD in C++, there would be nothing to leak and calling constructors/destructors is needless for such types.

Comment: @wormsparty: no. In C initializer and cleanup functions are made. Built in types have no issue without constructor and destructor, but their values are not defined in C, too.

Comment: Konstantin: Yes, it's close, but it's misleading. It almost implies that a "struct" is a "class instance". Anyway I think we will both agree that there really is no such entity as "a struct", when it gets right down to it. :) Pet hate: "there is no difference between a struct and a class, except..." -- only one exists!

Answer (score 4):

That's undefined behavior - memory allocated by `malloc()` in uninitialized, so using it as a struct containing `string` objects can lead to anything; I'd expect crashing. Since no-one invokes the destructor before calling `free()`, `string` objects won't be destroyed and their buffers will almost definitely leak.

Comment: Can't you use the placement new operator to initialize s1 and s2 in the newly allocated *d?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, you can, but you'll have to deal with possible exceptions yourself.

Comment: @Alex You can use placement new to construct `MyData` in the `malloc`'d memory. In that case you will also need to call `~MyData()` explicitly before `free`ing the memory.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using `malloc()` and `free()` in a C++ program; they're not constructor/destructor-aware.

Use the `new` and `delete` operators.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because the constructor and destructor are not called. Use `new` and `delete`.

Comment: The constructor of the strings are called since they are both allocated.

Comment: @wormsparty No, they are not. `malloc` just allocates memory, no constructor is called. That is what `new` is for.

Comment: @wormsparty: if use malloc, constructor is not called, so string classes constructor are not called, so the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you manage to initialize s1 and s2 properly, simply doing free(d) won't reclaim any memory dynamically allocated for s1 and s2. You should really create *d through new and destroy through delete, which will ensure proper destruction of s1 and s2 (and initialization as well).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are probably leaking, and your strings aren't properly constructed, either. The program's behaviour is undefined, meaning everything is going to go wrong.

The closest valid way to do what you're doing is *placement `new`*. Still, you'd be better off with some common base class and proper C++ polymorphism.

If the possible types are unrelated, you can use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html).